# Where to manage apostrophe-search index.html

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I am trying to incorporate the apostrophe-search module in my apostrophe cms project but am running into a template error.

I have been following the steps found in the [apostrophe cms documentation](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/howtos/search.html) and [npm apostrophe-search tutorial](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apostrophe-search#adding-the-mini-form-to-your-layout) to install apostrophe-search:

I have installed apostrophe-search in my project directory using npm:

```
npm install apostrophe-search
```

And I put this module in with my app.js file in the modules section.

The default search that comes with adding the module to app.js seems to be working okay (see below)

[default-apostrophe-search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI6Sx.png)

but when I try to follow the steps to customize this search I run into problems.

I have tried placing the following code block in my index.html in one of my apostrophe-pieces-pages to try and use the default functionality with the mini-search tool:

```
{% include "search:miniForm.html" %}
```

but was met with the following error:

```
e.stack:  Template render error: (vendor-pages:index.html)
Error: Module doesn't exist: search
```

I have also tried creating an apostrophe-search module folder in my project so that it looks like project/lib/modules/apostrophe-search/views/ and copied the index.html of the apostrophe-search module found in the node_modules library, but when I load the localhost:3000/search page I am met with another error:

```
e.stack:  Template render error: (apostrophe-search:index.html)
Template render error: (apostrophe-search:index.html)
Error: template not found: apostrophe-search:pagerMacros.html
```

This seems to be a problem with the way that my directory is structured, but I am not sure as I believe I have followed the steps in the documentation properly.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're using a very old version of apostrophe, you don't have to install the search module separately:

From the [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apostrophe-search):

> This module was for A2 0.5.x. For new projects, use Apostrophe 2, which has a built-in search module.

None of the instructions on the npm page are compatible with [the instructions for the built-in apostrophe-search](https://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/howtos/search.html) in Apostrophe 2.

Instead, you could place the example mini-form

```
<form method="GET" action="/search">
  <input type="text" name="q" /><input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

in `{project}/lib/modules/apostrophe-search/views/mini-form.html`

and then:

```
{% include "apostrophe-search:mini-form.html" %}
```

in your other templates.